# How to configure boost::graph to use my own (stable) index for vertices?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

The simplest `boost::adjacency_list` uses `std::size_t` as the underlying vertex_descriptor (index).

```
boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::vecS,
    boost::vecS,
    boost::directedS,
    boost::no_property,
    boost::no_property
>  graph;
```

Once I know the vertex descriptor, I can quickly access the desired vertex.

```
auto vertex = graph[idx]; // idx is the veretx descriptor
```

However, when the graph is mutated, there is no guarantee that the `vertex_decriptor` will be stable.

```
auto v0 = boost::add_vertex(graph);
auto v1 = boost::add_vertex(graph);
auto v2 = boost::add_vertex(graph);

boost::remove_vertex(v0, graph); // v1 and v2 are no longer valid
```

I would like to be able to find a specific vertex quickly - meaning I wish to avoid traversing the graph structure in search of a vertex I know exists.

My thinking is that I can somehow tweak `boost::adjacency_list` with a different selector to the VertexListS template parameter, that will allow me to use my own provided vertex_descripor (index).

I explored the possibility of using an associative container selector such as the builtin `boost::hash_mapS` but it seems I can't control the exact id it returns when calling `add_vertex`.
I would like to be able to use my own id (vertex_descriptor) for each vertex.

I'll try to be a bit more clear, with the code I wish would work:

```
// the following type will serve as the vertex_descriptor:
using my_id_type = std::size_t;

struct MyVertex
{
    my_id_type id;
    // some other fields
}

// add vertices with unique identifiers that will also serve as the vertex_descriptors
boost::add_vertex(MyVertex{1111}, graph); // I expect this to return 1111
boost::add_vertex(MyVertex{2222}, graph);
boost::add_vertex(MyVertex{1234}, graph);


boost::remove_vertex(1111, graph); // I expect this to remove the first vertex

// access a specific vertex using its unique, stable descriptor:
auto vertex = graph[1234];
```

Can this be achieved using boost::graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can this be achieved using boost::graph?

The answer is nearly always "yes" with BGL. It's one of the most profoundly generic library designs in existence.

---

To my surprise, something new appeared in the type-hierarchy for `adjacency_list`. Apparently these days there's a `named_graph` mixin (actually `maybe_name_graph`) which uses traits on the vertex bundle to detect an "internal name".

This means you can get close. Though the vertex descriptor will **not** become your id, you **can** have O(1) lookup. And the interface has some conveniences, so you **can** write:

```
add_edge(1111, 2222, g);
add_edge(2222, 1111, g);
```

Notes:

- the lookup is amortized O(1) because the name-vertex lookup is based on an unordered (hash) index
- you run into problems (e.g. ambiguous overloads for `add_edge`) if you make the `id` type accidentally the same as the `vertex_descriptor` type (or if your argument have equally "far" conversions to either).
- as far as I can tell, the internal name property is **not** automatically picked up as the `vertex_index_t` nor `vertex_name_t` property.

### Step #1: The Graph

```
struct Vertex {
    size_t      id;
    std::string other = "default-constructed";
};

using Graph =
    boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, Vertex>;
```

So far no surprises. I

- opted to add a second member `other` just to show when/how it gets default constructed
- opted `listS` because it

  - a. offers reference/descriptor stability (except for removed vertices)
  - b. leads to opaque `vertex_descriptor` (`void*`) which does not conflict with the id type (`size_t`) in overload resolution

### Step #2: Name Traits

Next we teach BGL about our Internal Vertex Name.

> *This is purely parameterized by `Vertex` bundle, so keep in mind that different graphs using the same bundle would use the same name traits.*

```
// traits
template <> struct boost::graph::internal_vertex_name<Vertex> {
    struct type {
        using result_type = size_t;
        result_type const& operator()(Vertex const& bundle) const {
            return bundle.id;
        }
    };
};

template <> struct boost::graph::internal_vertex_constructor<Vertex> {
    struct type {
      private:
        using extract_name_type = typename internal_vertex_name<Vertex>::type;

        using vertex_name_type = typename remove_cv<typename remove_reference<
            typename extract_name_type::result_type>::type>::type;

      public:
        using argument_type = vertex_name_type;
        using result_type = Vertex;

        result_type operator()(const vertex_name_type& id) const {
            return {id};
        }
    };
};
```

Note

- We could of course hard-code the knowns in the second specialization:

  ```
   template <> struct boost::graph::internal_vertex_constructor<Vertex> {
       struct type {
           Vertex operator()(size_t id) const { return {id}; }
       };
   };
  ```
- It is *very* important to return the id by reference. Failing to do so leads to [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) with no diagnostics from the library/compiler

### Step #3 Adding/Finding Vertices

Now you can add vertices. Either by "name" (your `id`):

```
auto x = add_vertex(1111, g);                // by id
```

Or the old-fashioned way you anticipated in the question:

```
add_vertex(Vertex{2222, "twotwotwotwo"}, g); // or with full bundle
```

Duplicate additions have no effect:

```
assert(add_vertex(1111, g) == x);
```

Different lookups exist. The `vertex_by_property` returns a `optional<vertex_descriptor>` given a vertex bundle.

```
assert(x == *g.vertex_by_property(g[x]));
```

It does so by extracting the "internal name" from the bundle passed, so there is no need for the bundle to contain any other state outside the id:

```
assert(x == *g.vertex_by_property(Vertex{1111}));
```

Although it *feels* like an implementation detail, the actual `multi_index_container` implementing the name -> descriptor index is also exposed:

```
assert(x == *g.named_vertices.find(1111));
```

### Step #4 Adding Edges

```
add_edge(1111, 2222, g);
add_edge(2222, 1111, g);
```

That borrows a page from your previous question :)

Obviously, you can still add edges by vertex descriptors.

### Step #5 Other Operations

Borrowing more pages from that previous answer:

```
print_graph(g, get(&Vertex::id, g), std::cout << "---\n");
print_graph(g, get(&Vertex::other, g), std::cout << "---\n");

std::cout << "---\n";
for (auto *v : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g))) {
    auto const& [id, other] = g[v];
    std::cout << id << " " << std::quoted(other) << "\n";
}

if (auto v = g.vertex_by_property({1111})) {
    std::cout << "==== removing " << g[*v].id << "\n";
    clear_vertex(*v, g);  // clear edges
    remove_vertex(*v, g); // remove the vertex
}

print_graph(g, get(&Vertex::id, g), std::cout << "---\n");
print_graph(g, get(&Vertex::other, g), std::cout << "---\n");
```

### Full Demo

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31ee6f1f430514e5)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

struct Vertex {
    size_t      id;
    std::string other = "default-constructed";
};

using Graph =
    boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, Vertex>;

// traits
template <> struct boost::graph::internal_vertex_name<Vertex> {
    struct type {
        using result_type = size_t;
        result_type const& operator()(Vertex const& bundle) const {
            return bundle.id;
        }
    };
};

template <> struct boost::graph::internal_vertex_constructor<Vertex> {
    struct type {
      private:
        using extractor = typename internal_vertex_name<Vertex>::type;
        using name_t    = std::decay_t<typename extractor::result_type>;

      public:
        using argument_type = name_t;
        using result_type = Vertex;

        result_type operator()(const name_t& id) const { return {id}; }
    };
};

int main() {
    Graph g;

    {
        auto x = add_vertex(1111, g);                // by id
        add_vertex(Vertex{2222, "twotwotwotwo"}, g); // or with full bundle

        // duplicate additions have no effect
        assert(add_vertex(1111, g) == x);

        // different lookups exist
        assert(x == *g.named_vertices.find(1111));
        assert(x == *g.vertex_by_property(Vertex{1111}));
        assert(x == *g.vertex_by_property(g[x]));
    }

    add_edge(1111, 2222, g);
    add_edge(2222, 1111, g);

    print_graph(g, get(&Vertex::id, g), std::cout << "---\n");
    print_graph(g, get(&Vertex::other, g), std::cout << "---\n");

    std::cout << "---\n";
    for (auto *v : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g))) {
        auto const& [id, other] = g[v];
        std::cout << id << " " << std::quoted(other) << "\n";
    }

    if (auto v = g.vertex_by_property({1111})) {
        std::cout << "==== removing " << g[*v].id << "\n";
        clear_vertex(*v, g);  // clear edges
        remove_vertex(*v, g); // remove the vertex
    }

    print_graph(g, get(&Vertex::id, g), std::cout << "---\n");
    print_graph(g, get(&Vertex::other, g), std::cout << "---\n");
}
```

Prints

```
---
1111 --> 2222 
2222 --> 1111 
---
default-constructed --> twotwotwotwo 
twotwotwotwo --> default-constructed 
---
1111 "default-constructed"
2222 "twotwotwotwo"
==== removing 1111
---
2222 --> 
---
twotwotwotwo -->
```

#### Sidenote:

- you cannot use an associative container selector for vertices. Specifying `hash_mapS` leads to `unordered_set<void*, hash<void*>, equal_to<void*>, allocator<void*>>` as the `m_vertices` type.

Comment: PS. I just remembered that `vertex_index` is assumed (by BGL algorithms) to map to the contiguous domain `[0, num_vertices(g))` so the given values would not satisfy the requirements, making it unsafe to actually use it as the vertex id.

Comment: I wonder why the internal  multi_index_container doesn't replace the underlying std::list entirely as a vertex list. If I read the documentation correctly, that is the purpose of a multi_index_container, allowing multiple types of access to a container so it can behave as an std::list and a hash table at the same time.

Comment: Probably for separation of concerns. Now the mixin can apply to any PropertyGraph, not just adjacency_list