# Access vertex via vertex_index property?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

Is there a built-in way in BGL to access a vertex via its vertex_index property?

```cpp
using VertexProperties = boost::property<boost::vertex_index_t, int>;
using DirectedGraph = boost::adjacency_list<
   boost::listS, 
   boost::vecS, 
   boost::directedS, 
   VertexProperties,
   boost::no_property>;
using VertexDescriptor = boost::graph_traits<DirectedGraph>::vertex_descriptor;
using EdgeDescriptor = boost::graph_traits<DirectedGraph>::edge_descriptor;

int main()
{
    DirectedGraph g;
    auto indices = boost::get(boost::vertex_index, g);

    boost::add_vertex(DirectedGraph::vertex_property_type{123123}, g); // unique index
    boost::add_vertex(DirectedGraph::vertex_property_type{451345}, g); // unique index

    // how do I access the vertex with my unique index?

    // I only see the way from vertex->vertex_index via the property map
    indices[x];

}
```

Comment: The usual suggestion for this sort of thing is to use the bundled properties feature.  https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/graph/doc/bundles.html.  This is easier and far more flexible.

Comment: With bundled properties the same issue applies though, doesnt it?

Comment: The flexibility of bundled properties allows you to design for your particular requirements ( which you have not described ).  Perhaps something like this: when you add a vertex and its bundled class, store a pointer to the bundled class in a map keyed by your index number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By far the most user-friendly solution in this realm is to use internal name properties. This is a mixin-feature for `boost::adjacency_list` (implemented in `maybe_named_graph`).

Moreover, your approach "repurposing" `vertex_index_t` for this is probably misguided: vertex indices are a library "contract" which assumes that it maps all vertices `vertices(g)` to a contiguous integral domain `[0, num_vertices(g))`. Your ID doesn't satisfy those properties so it will lead to unspecified, and most likely [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) when you invoke BGL algorithms on your graph.

All in all, I'd redefine the properties as your own bundle:

```
struct VertexProps {
    int my_id;
    VertexProps(int id) : my_id(std::move(id)) {}
};

using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, VertexProps,
                                    boost::no_property>;
using V     = Graph::vertex_descriptor;
using E     = Graph::edge_descriptor;
```

Now you need to specialize some traits to tell `maybe_named_graph` that some part of `VertexProps` is your vertex name:

```
template <> struct boost::graph::internal_vertex_name<VertexProps> {
    struct type {
        using result_type = int;
        int const& operator()(VertexProps const& vp) const { return vp.my_id; }
    };
};

template <> struct boost::graph::internal_vertex_constructor<VertexProps> {
    struct type {
        auto operator()(int const& value) const { return VertexProps{value}; }
    };
};
```

Now you can add vertices by name:

```
V a = add_vertex(123123, g); // unique index
V b = add_vertex(451345, g); // unique index
```

But instead of using `a` or `b` you can keep using the name for subsequent operations:

```
add_edge(123123, 451345, g);
```

You can get vertex descriptors from the property explicitly:

```
V va = *g.vertex_by_property(123123);
V vb = *g.vertex_by_property(451345);
```

As a surprise bit of user-friendliness, you don't even need to create vertices ahead of time:

```
add_edge(234234, 562456, g);
```

will magically add the two new, named, vertices.

### Live Demo

[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/89bcb1ebfe5cd6d8)

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>

struct VertexProps {
    int my_id;
    VertexProps(int id) : my_id(std::move(id)) {}
};

template <> struct boost::graph::internal_vertex_name<VertexProps> {
    struct type {
        using result_type = int;
        int const& operator()(VertexProps const& vp) const { return vp.my_id; }
    };
};

template <> struct boost::graph::internal_vertex_constructor<VertexProps> {
    struct type {
        auto operator()(int const& value) const { return VertexProps{value}; }
    };
};

using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, VertexProps,
                                    boost::no_property>;
using V     = Graph::vertex_descriptor;
using E     = Graph::edge_descriptor;

int main() {
    Graph g;
    print_graph(g, get(&VertexProps::my_id, g), std::cout << "\n --- Empty:\n");
    auto my_id = get(&VertexProps::my_id, g);

    V a = add_vertex(123123, g); // unique index
    V b = add_vertex(451345, g); // unique index
    print_graph(g, my_id, std::cout << "\n --- Vertices:\n");

    std::cout << g[a].my_id << std::endl;
    std::cout << g[b].my_id << std::endl;

    add_edge(123123, 451345, g);
    print_graph(g, my_id, std::cout << "\n --- Edge:\n");

    V va = *g.vertex_by_property(123123);
    V vb = *g.vertex_by_property(451345);
    add_edge(vb, va, g);
    print_graph(g, my_id, std::cout << "\n --- Edges:\n");

    add_edge(234234, 562456, g);
    print_graph(g, my_id, std::cout << "\n --- Magically added:\n");
}
```

Prints

```
 --- Empty:

 --- Vertices:
123123 --> 
451345 --> 
123123
451345

 --- Edge:
123123 --> 451345 
451345 --> 

 --- Edges:
123123 --> 451345 
451345 --> 123123 

 --- Magically added:
123123 --> 451345 
451345 --> 123123 
562456 --> 
234234 --> 562456
```

### More and Caveats

There are a number of interesting edge cases around this. You can read more about them here:

[How to use boost graph algorithm on a named graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71540438/how-to-use-boost-graph-algorithm-on-a-named-graph/71543159#71543159)