# Boost Graph Library write graphviz format with simple vertex property (string)

Tags: c++, graph, boost, graphviz, boost-graph

## Objective:

I want to wrap a Boost Graph into a class on which I have a bit more control, reduce the noise in the main function, and print a graphviz format.

### Problem

The code fails to compile, returning a `include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:2601:27: error: cannot form a reference to 'void'`

### Minimal reproducible example

The code compiles on Compiler Explorer https://godbolt.org/z/9beKovxc9
But if you uncomment the last line of main the error is reproduced.

```cpp
// BGL
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/visitors.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/breadth_first_search.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>

#include <iostream>                // std::cout
#include <functional>              // std::function
#include <utility>                 // std::pair

///
/// @brief Defines the desired properties and constraints for a coalescent graph
///
struct tree_traits
{
  ///
  /// @brief Trees are sparse graph in nature, adjacency_matrix would not be justified here
  ///
  template<class... Types>
  using implementation = boost::adjacency_list<Types...>;
  ///
  /// @brief We want to enforce avoiding multi-graphs (edges with same end nodes)
  ///
  using out_edge_list_type = boost::setS;
  ///
  /// @brief We are prioritizing speed for space
  ///
  using vertex_list_type = boost::listS;
  ///
  /// @brief Coalescent trees are directed acyclic graphs
  ///
  using directed_type = boost::directedS ;
}; // end tree_traits

///
/// @brief A graph with properties suited to represent a coalescent tree
///
template<class VertexProperties=boost::no_property, class EdgeProperties=boost::no_property>
class Tree
{
public:
  ///
  /// @brief Properties of an edge, like the demes visited
  /// @see https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/graph/doc/bundles.html
  ///
  using edge_properties = EdgeProperties;
  ///
  /// @brief Properties of a vertex, like the mutational state
  /// @see https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/graph/doc/bundles.html
  ///
  using vertex_properties = VertexProperties;
  ///
  /// @brief The type of graph hold by the tree class
  ///
  using graph_type = tree_traits::implementation
  <
  tree_traits::out_edge_list_type,
  tree_traits::vertex_list_type,
  tree_traits::directed_type,
  VertexProperties,
  EdgeProperties
  >;
private:
  graph_type _graph;
  static constexpr bool vertex_prop_undefined = std::is_same<vertex_properties,boost::no_property>::value;
  static constexpr bool edge_prop_undefined = std::is_same<edge_properties,boost::no_property>::value;
  
public:
  /// @note adds an object-oriented layer
  auto add_vertex(auto&&... args)
  {
    return boost::add_vertex(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)..., _graph);
  }
  
  /// @note adds an object-oriented layer
  /// @note order of vertices determines edge orientation
  auto add_edge(auto&&... args)
  {
    return boost::add_edge(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)..., _graph);
  }
  
  void to_graphviz(std::ostream& out) const
  {
    using namespace boost;
    return boost::write_graphviz(out, _graph,
      boost::make_label_writer(boost::get(vertex_bundle, this->_graph)),
      boost::make_label_writer(boost::get(edge_bundle, this->_graph))
    );
  }
};
  
int main()
{
  using q_tree_type = Tree<std::string, double>;
  q_tree_type graph;
  
  // We insert the root of tree
  auto root = graph.add_vertex("first");
  //graph.to_graphviz(std::cout); // <--- huho
}
```

### What I can think of

- I thought that (maybe) having a pure `std::string` as `VertexProperties` rather than a custom structure confuses the compiler. I tried to disambiguate with `if constexpr`, to use a `default_writer` if the `VertexProperties` type evaluated to `no_property`. But no success on this front, but here is the embarassingly naive code I wrote

```cpp
    // member of Tree<...> class
    void to_graphviz(std::ostream& out) const
    {
      using namespace boost;
    
      if constexpr (vertex_prop_undefined)
      {
        if constexpr (edge_prop_undefined)
          return write_graphviz(out, _graph);
    
        return boost::write_graphviz(out, _graph, default_writer(), boost::make_label_writer(boost::get(edge_bundle, this->_graph)));
      }
      if constexpr (edge_prop_undefined)
        return write_graphviz(out, _graph, boost::make_label_writer(boost::get(vertex_bundle, this->_graph)));
    
      return boost::write_graphviz(out, _graph, boost::make_label_writer(boost::get(vertex_bundle, this->_graph)), boost::make_label_writer(boost::get(edge_bundle, this->_graph)));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with displaying the bundle. `std::string` and `double` are both output-streamable, so they will work fine.

Your problem is the classical one: you selected a graph model with no suitable implicit vertex index. This is due to the choice:

```
  ///
  /// @brief We are prioritizing speed for space
  ///
  using vertex_list_type = boost::listS;
```

> *Note that, at least in general terms, the comment claim is pretty
> inaccurate. The sole reason to select `listS` is because*
>
> - *insert/erase can be more consistent time (but slower),*
> - *vertex descriptors and iterators can be stable (unless erased)*

But for now, let's demonstrate that `write_graphviz` already works with `vecS` instead:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/EEj1s6zv4)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct tree_traits {
    template <class... Types> using model = boost::adjacency_list<Types...>;
    using out_edge_list_type              = boost::setS;
    using vertex_list_type                = boost::vecS; // listS;
    using directed_type                   = boost::directedS;
};

template <class VertexProperties = boost::no_property,
          class EdgeProperties   = boost::no_property>
struct Tree {
    using edge_properties   = EdgeProperties;   // like the demes visited
    using vertex_properties = VertexProperties; // like the mutational state
    using graph_type =
        tree_traits::model<tree_traits::out_edge_list_type, tree_traits::vertex_list_type,
                           tree_traits::directed_type, VertexProperties, EdgeProperties>;

  private:
    graph_type _graph;
    static constexpr bool vertex_prop_undefined = std::is_same_v<vertex_properties, boost::no_property>;
    static constexpr bool edge_prop_undefined = std::is_same_v<edge_properties, boost::no_property>;

  public:
    /// @note adds an object-oriented layer
    auto add_vertex(auto&&... args) {
        return boost::add_vertex(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)..., _graph);
    }

    /// @note adds an object-oriented layer
    /// @note order of vertices determines edge orientation
    auto add_edge(auto&&... args) {
        return boost::add_edge(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)..., _graph);
    }

    void to_graphviz(std::ostream& out) const {
        using namespace boost;
        return boost::write_graphviz(
            out, _graph,
            boost::make_label_writer(boost::get(vertex_bundle, this->_graph)),
            boost::make_label_writer(boost::get(edge_bundle, this->_graph)));
    }
};

int main() {
    using q_tree_type = Tree<std::string, double>;
    q_tree_type tree;

    auto first  = tree.add_vertex("first");
    auto second = tree.add_vertex("second");
    auto third  = tree.add_vertex("second");

    tree.add_edge(first, second, 444.4);
    tree.add_edge(first, third, 555.5);

    tree.to_graphviz(std::cout);
}
```

Prints

```
digraph G {
0[label=first];
1[label=second];
2[label=second];
0->1 [label=444.39999999999998];
0->2 [label=555.5];
}
```

### Workarounds?

I'd stick with `vecS`. The interface of `Tree<>` doesn't allow for inserting vertices except at the end. You currently don't show interface for removing vertices. This means that neither reallocation cost nor stability are reasons for preferring `listS`.

If you must use a node-based vertex container selector, you're responsible for adding an index for the algorithms that require it:

```
void to_graphviz(std::ostream& out) const {
    boost::container::flat_map<typename graph_type::vertex_descriptor, size_t> index;
    index.reserve(num_vertices(_graph));
    // OR just: std::map<typename graph_type::vertex_descriptor, size_t> index;

    for (size_t i = 0; auto v : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(_graph)))
        index[v] = i++;

    return write_graphviz(                                    //
        out, _graph,                                          //
        make_label_writer(get(boost::vertex_bundle, _graph)), //
        make_label_writer(get(boost::edge_bundle, _graph)),   //
        boost::default_writer{},                              //
        boost::make_assoc_property_map(index));
}
```

### Live Demo

Putting that in action as well:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/9Mc5fsPr7)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

#include <boost/container/flat_map.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/property_map.hpp>

struct tree_traits {
    template <class... Types> using model = boost::adjacency_list<Types...>;
    using out_edge_list_type              = boost::setS;
    using vertex_list_type                = boost::listS;
    using directed_type                   = boost::directedS;
};

template <class VertexProperties = boost::no_property,
        class EdgeProperties   = boost::no_property>
struct Tree {
    using edge_properties   = EdgeProperties;   // like the demes visited
    using vertex_properties = VertexProperties; // like the mutational state
    using graph_type =
        tree_traits::model<tree_traits::out_edge_list_type, tree_traits::vertex_list_type,
                        tree_traits::directed_type, VertexProperties, EdgeProperties>;

private:
    graph_type _graph;
    static constexpr bool vertex_prop_undefined = std::is_same_v<vertex_properties, boost::no_property>;
    static constexpr bool edge_prop_undefined = std::is_same_v<edge_properties, boost::no_property>;

public:
    /// @note adds an object-oriented layer
    auto add_vertex(auto&&... args) {
        return boost::add_vertex(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)..., _graph);
    }

    /// @note adds an object-oriented layer
    /// @note order of vertices determines edge orientation
    auto add_edge(auto&&... args) {
        return boost::add_edge(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)..., _graph);
    }

    void to_graphviz(std::ostream& out) const {
        boost::container::flat_map<typename graph_type::vertex_descriptor, size_t> index;
        index.reserve(num_vertices(_graph));
        // OR just: std::map<typename graph_type::vertex_descriptor, size_t> index;

        for (size_t i = 0; auto v : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(_graph)))
            index[v] = i++;

        return write_graphviz(                                    //
            out, _graph,                                          //
            make_label_writer(get(boost::vertex_bundle, _graph)), //
            make_label_writer(get(boost::edge_bundle, _graph)),   //
            boost::default_writer{},                              //
            boost::make_assoc_property_map(index));
    }
};

int main() {
    using q_tree_type = Tree<std::string, double>;
    q_tree_type tree;

    auto first  = tree.add_vertex("first");
    auto second = tree.add_vertex("second");
    auto third  = tree.add_vertex("second");

    tree.add_edge(first, second, 444.4);
    tree.add_edge(first, third, 555.5);

    tree.to_graphviz(std::cout);
}
```

Prints

```
digraph G {
0[label=first];
1[label=second];
2[label=second];
0->1 [label=444.39999999999998];
0->2 [label=555.5];
}
```

### Notes

Note that most algorithms require the vertex index. E.g. `breadth_first_search` (which you already have the include for) [requires it to create the default color map](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/graph/doc/breadth_first_search.html). You can get around it by supplying a custom color map instead for that particular example, examples:

- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71540438/how-to-use-boost-graph-algorithm-on-a-named-graph/71543159#71543159:~:text=Pass%20Your%20Own%20Color%20Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71540438/how-to-use-boost-graph-algorithm-on-a-named-graph/71543159#71543159:%7E:text=Pass%20Your%20Own%20Color%20Map)
- [What is required for a custom BGL graph to work with topological sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66352055/what-is-required-for-a-custom-bgl-graph-to-work-with-topological-sort/66352925#66352925)

Comment: Omg I would never have found the problem was with `listS`! Concerning the inacurate statement, it comes from a (naive) reading of the documentation: `The std::list has a higher per-vertex space overhead than the std::vector, storing three extra pointers per vertex.`. Well thank you SO much!

Comment: Yeah, storage efficiency is *also* a factor, but not the only one :) It *is* possible to create access patterns that will be faster with `listS`, as well. They'd be unusual (and impossible for the interface shown), but not impossible. Always let the profiler guide you.