# Boost Graphs - deterministic graph behaviour from JSON

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I'm creating graphs from a JSON array file and I'd like it so that when I traverse through both edges and vertices (e.g. in_edges(), vertices() or topological_sort() ) of the graph, it's in the exact same order regardless of the insertion order. In other words, to produce the same graph even if I shuffle the order of the JSON.

The JSON could look like this:

```
[
    {
        "ID": 10,
        "PARENTS": [2, 1, 85]
    },
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "PARENTS": []
    },
    {
        "ID": 99,
        "PARENTS": [2]
    },
    {
        "ID": 2,
        "PARENTS": []
    }, 
    {
        "ID": 85,
        "PARENTS": [99]
    },
]
```

As an example, if the insertion order was as the example JSON, 10 -> 1 -> 99 -> 2 -> 85, then the parents of 10 would come up as 1 2 85. However, if the insertion order was instead 85 -> 2 -> 1 -> 99 -> 10, then the parents of 10 would come up as 85 2 1. This is what I'd like to avoid.

Right now I'm considering adding a wrapper around a boost graph and sorting the vertices with a set when you call getParent() for example but I wanted to know if there was an easier way to do achieve this with boost natively.

Another possibility is to sort the JSON beforehand but I'd like to avoid that time complexity.

Comment: The JSON you quote is not JSON (i.e. not valid). That said, if you use a `set` (which is ordered automatically), it doesn't matter in which order you insert elements, the outcome is the same.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt but Boost Graph algorithms don't work on standard containers. They require [Graph Concepts](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/graph/doc/graph_concepts.html)

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html and https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/graph/doc/using_adjacency_list.html#sec:custom-storage document how you can customize the containers. And yes, they seem to be based on standard containers by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to avoid that time complexity

Given the laws of thermodynamics, this cannot be avoided. You explicitly state that you want normalized/canonical results, which means you have to expend the energy to ... normalize the data, regardless of whether it's done in pre- or post-processing.

Prefer to do it early, so the effort is not repeated.

Remember Boost Graph is already deterministic. What you want is to treat the input in normalized fashion. Let's reproduce the issue first, given two JSON documents `doc1` and `doc2` from the question:

```
#include <boost/json.hpp>
namespace json = boost::json;

auto opts = json::parse_options{.allow_trailing_commas=true};
auto doc1 = json::parse(
    R"( [
    { "ID": 10, "PARENTS": [2,  1, 85] },
    { "ID": 1,  "PARENTS": []   },
    { "ID": 99, "PARENTS": [2]  },
    { "ID": 2,  "PARENTS": []   },
    { "ID": 85, "PARENTS": [99] },
])", {}, opts);

auto doc2 = json::parse(
    R"([
     { "PARENTS": [99]       , "ID": 85  },
     { "PARENTS": []         , "ID": 2   },
     { "PARENTS": []         , "ID": 1   },
     { "PARENTS": [2]        , "ID": 99  },
     { "PARENTS": [2,  1, 85], "ID": 10  },
])", {}, opts);
```

If we 1:1 translate these to `boost::adjacency_list<>`:

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
using Id = int64_t;

namespace Builder {
    struct Node {
        using Parents = std::vector<int64_t>;
        Id      id;
        Parents parents;

        friend Node tag_invoke(json::value_to_tag<Node>, json::value const& j) {
            return {j.at("ID").as_int64(), value_to<Parents>(j.at("PARENTS"))};
        }
    };

    auto Read(json::value const& doc) {
        boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, Id> g;

        for (auto& [id, parents] : value_to<std::vector<Node>>(doc))
            for (auto parent : parents)
                add_edge(parent, id, g);

        return g;
    }
} // namespace Builder
```

We indeed see the different graphs as expected: **[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/492561a6c0f040cc)**

```cpp
int main() {
    std::cout << doc1 << "\n";
    std::cout << doc2 << "\n";
    std::cout << (doc1 == doc2 ? "EQUAL" : "DIFFERENT") << "\n";

    auto g1 = Builder::Read(doc1);
    auto g2 = Builder::Read(doc2);

    std::cout << g1 << "\n";
    std::cout << g2 << "\n";

    auto s1 = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(g1);
    auto s2 = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(g2);
    std::cout << (s1 == s2 ? "EQUAL" : "DIFFERENT") << "\n";
}
```

Printing

```
[{"ID":10,"PARENTS":[2,1,85]},{"ID":1,"PARENTS":[]},{"ID":99,"PARENTS":[2]},{"ID":2,"PARENTS":[]},{"ID":85,"PARENTS":[99]}]
[{"PARENTS":[99],"ID":85},{"PARENTS":[],"ID":2},{"PARENTS":[],"ID":1},{"PARENTS":[2],"ID":99},{"PARENTS":[2,1,85],"ID":10}]
DIFFERENT
10 --> 
2 --> 10 99 
1 --> 10 
85 --> 10 
99 --> 85 

85 --> 10 
99 --> 85 
2 --> 99 10 
10 --> 
1 --> 10 

DIFFERENT
```

### Preprocessing Nodes

In this case we can very simply cause the nodes to be inserted in a canonical ordering of our choosing by replacing:

```
for (auto& [id, parents] : value_to<std::vector<Node>>(doc))
```

with

```
for (auto& [id, parents] : value_to<std::set<Node>>(doc))
```

For simplicity let's go with the default ordering based on each node properties:

```
struct Node { /*...*/
    auto operator<=>(Node const&) const = default;
```

Now we get **[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c6b058cd1e8f90f)**

```
// ...
10 --> 
2 --> 10 99 
1 --> 10 
85 --> 10 
99 --> 85 

EQUAL
```

### BONUS: What About The Adjacencies

You didn't ask, but how about the order of the parents?

```
auto doc3 = json::parse(
    R"([
     { "PARENTS": [99]       , "ID": 85  },
     { "PARENTS": []         , "ID": 2   },
     { "PARENTS": []         , "ID": 1   },
     { "PARENTS": [2]        , "ID": 99  },
     { "PARENTS": [85, 2,  1], "ID": 10  },
])", {}, opts);
```

Now gives

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af36efe6a2f29733)**

```
g2 EQUAL
g3 DIFFERENT
```

In pre-processing again coercing the adjacencies into an ordered container ([Live](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/daa47c73bd5be699)):

```
 using Parents = std::multiset<int64_t>; // g3 EQUAL
```

> - *To disallow duplicate edges, use `std::set`*
> - *In the graph model with `multisetS` [doesn't quite do enough](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a52c0c062817314) because it orders on the descriptor.*

Comment: Note: I used `internal_vertex_name` trait to simplify the graph model configuration. Note that I'm avoiding a pitfall when `Id` becomes the same type as the vertex descriptor (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71488845/how-to-configure-boostgraph-to-use-my-own-stable-index-for-vertices#:~:text=you%20run%20into%20problems%20(e.g.%20ambiguous%20overloads%20for%20add_edge)%20if%20you%20make%20the%20id%20type%20accidentally%20the%20same%20as%20the%20vertex_descriptor%20type), e.g. [Live](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/21edd143e08457c3))

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have to ask though, what are the benefits to inserting based on sets rather than sorting the JSON by ID at the very start?

Comment: Usually sorting JSON is not supported by the library. It is likely less efficient to sort node-based containers of JSON value objects. But if your JSON library supports it, you can obviously measure which is better performing.

Comment: I'm using nlohmann's JSON library which has a JSON swap function. Will do on the measuring. Thank you!